# Redirect to third party payment gateway using POST authentication

Tags: xml, magento, payment-gateway

I have an almost complete solution for a custom payment method in Magento. I followed [this] http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/ excellent tutorial on how to do it but I am now stuck with an authentication problem.

I contacted the gateway and an IT representative told me that I must post the correct values to the gateway for authentication. These values must also be sent in XML format:

Testmode Username: ######
Testmode Password: ######
Testmode MerchantID: #####
Testmode TerminalID:#####
BIN = ######1

I've created a system.xml in my the gateway module with the correct fields:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <sections>
    <payment>
      <groups>
        <mygateway translate="label comment" module="mygateway">
          <label>My Module mygateway</label>
          <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
          <sort_order>0</sort_order>
          <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
          <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
          <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
          <fields>
            <active translate="label">
              <label>Enabled</label>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
              <sort_order>10</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </active>
            <title translate="label">
              <label>My Module mygateway Paymentech</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>20</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            </title>
            <order_status translate="label">
              <label>New Order Status</label>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status</source_model>
              <sort_order>50</sort_order>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </order_status>
            <allowspecific translate="label">
              <label>Payment Applicable From</label>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>61</sort_order>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries</source_model>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            </allowspecific>
            <specificcountry translate="label">
              <label>Countries Payment Applicable From</label>
              <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
              <sort_order>70</sort_order>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <depends>
                <allowspecific>1</allowspecific>
              </depends>
            </specificcountry>
            <sort_order translate="label">
              <label>Sort Order</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            </sort_order>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            <test_apiusername translate="label">
                            <label>Test Mode Username</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </test_apiusername>
                        <test_apipassword translate="label">
                            <label>Test Mode Password</label>
                            <frontend_type>obscure</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </test_apipassword>
                        <test_MerchantID translate="label">
                            <label>Test Mode MerchantID</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </test_MerchantID>
                        <test_TerminalID translate="label">
                            <label>Test Mode TerminalID</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>9</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </test_TerminalID>
                        <test_BINNumber translate="label">
                            <label>Test Mode BIN</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </test_BINNumber>
                        <test_cgi_url>
                            <label>Test Mode Gateway URL</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>11</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <comment>Above values should be entered for Test account</comment>
                        </test_cgi_url>
                        <apiusername translate="label">
                            <label><![CDATA[<strong>Production</strong>]]> Mode Username</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>12</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </apiusername>
                        <apipassword translate="label">
                            <label><![CDATA[<strong>Production</strong>]]> Mode Password</label>
                            <frontend_type>obscure</frontend_type>
                            <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_encrypted</backend_model>
                            <sort_order>13</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </apipassword>
                        <MerchantID translate="label">
                            <label><![CDATA[<strong>Production</strong>]]> Mode MerchantID</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>14</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </MerchantID>
                        <TerminalID translate="label">
                            <label><![CDATA[<strong>Production</strong>]]> Mode TerminalID</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>15</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </TerminalID>
                        <BINNumber translate="label">
                            <label><![CDATA[<strong>Production</strong>]]> Mode BIN</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>16</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </BINNumber>
          </fields>
        </mygateway>
      </groups>
    </payment>
  </sections>
</config>
```

I am a unsure about the implementation the POST values needed for authentication into the PaymentController.php

```
<?php

class Myname_Mygateway_PaymentController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {
    // The redirect action is triggered when someone places an order
    public function redirectAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mage_Core_Block_Template','mygateway',array('template' => 'mygateway/redirect.phtml'));
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    // The response action is triggered when your gateway sends back a response after processing the customer's payment
    public function responseAction() {
        if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

            /*
            /* Your gateway's code to make sure the reponse you
            /* just got is from the gatway and not from some weirdo.
            /* This generally has some checksum or other checks,
            /* and is provided by the gateway.
            /* For now, we assume that the gateway's response is valid
            */

            $validated = true;
            $orderId = '123'; // Generally sent by gateway

            if($validated) {
                // Payment was successful, so update the order's state, send order email and move to the success page
                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
                $order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
                $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true, 'Gateway has authorized the payment.');

                $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                $order->setEmailSent(true);

                $order->save();

                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsQuoteId();

                Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
            }
            else {
                // There is a problem in the response we got
                $this->cancelAction();
                Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('checkout/onepage/failure', array('_secure'=>true));
            }
        }
        else
            Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('');
    }

    // The cancel action is triggered when an order is to be cancelled
    public function cancelAction() {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()) {
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
            if($order->getId()) {
                // Flag the order as 'cancelled' and save it
                $order->cancel()->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true, 'Gateway has declined the payment.')->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the form which redirects ie redirect.phtml

```
<?php
// Retrieve order
$_order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$_order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
?>
<form name="mygatewayform" method="post" action="http://www.gateway.com/the_url_they_gave_me">
    <input type="hidden" name="orderid" value="<?php echo $orderId; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="grandtotal" value="<?php echo $_order->getBaseGrandTotal(); ?>">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.mygatewayform.submit();
</script>
```

I was able to run a test order but the gateway only received my order due to IP logging and it was in the incorrect format. I've been searching the Magento forums and Google for nearly three weeks before posting here but I have found no solution. The gateway are unable to help as the have no Magento integration manual available either.

I'd be really grateful for some assistance if its not too much trouble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction that your following is for creating a payment that will redirect to a third party gateway.

`The URL that the payment gateway needs to redirect to on your web site after processing the customer’s payment (based on the naming we’ve used in this example) should be: http://www.yourwebsite.com/mygateway/payment/response .`

The best way to do what your trying to accomplish is to follow this http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method-api-based .

Also see

> /app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/Model/Authorizenet.php

```
//create xml and send info to gateway
private function callApi(Varien_Object $payment, $amount,$type){

    //call your authorize api here, incase of error throw exception.
    //only example code written below to show flow of code

    /*
     $order = $payment->getOrder();
    $types = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getCcTypes();
    if (isset($types[$payment->getCcType()])) {
    $type = $types[$payment->getCcType()];
    }
    $billingaddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $totals = number_format($amount, 2, '.', '');
    $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
    $currencyDesc = $order->getBaseCurrencyCode();

    $url = $this->getConfigData('gateway_url');
    $fields = array(
            'api_username'=> $this->getConfigData('api_username'),
            'api_password'=> $this->getConfigData('api_password'),
            ......

            'customer_firstname'=> $billingaddress->getData('firstname'),
            'customer_lastname'=> $billingaddress->getData('lastname'),
            'customer_phone'=> $billingaddress->getData('telephone'),
            'customer_email'=> $billingaddress->getData('email'),
            'customer_ipaddress'=> $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'bill_firstname'=> $billingaddress->getData('firstname'),
            'bill_lastname'=> $billingaddress->getData('lastname'),
            'Bill_address1'=> $billingaddress->getData('street'),
            'bill_city'=> $billingaddress->getData('city'),
            'bill_country'=> $billingaddress->getData('country_id'),
            'bill_state'=> $billingaddress->getData('region'),
            'bill_zip'=> $billingaddress->getData('postcode'),
            'customer_cc_expmo'=> $payment->getCcExpMonth(),
            'customer_cc_expyr'=> $payment->getCcExpYear(),
            'customer_cc_number'=> $payment->getCcNumber(),
            'customer_cc_type'=> strtoupper($type),
            'customer_cc_cvc'=> $payment->getCcCid(),
            'merchant_ref_number'=> $order->getIncrementId(),
            'currencydesc'=>$currencyDesc,
            'amount'=>$totals
    );

    $fields_string="";
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $fields_string = substr($fields_string,0,-1);
    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER ,0); // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,1); // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120); // Timeout on connect (2 minutes)
    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    */

    return array('status'=>1,'transaction_id' => time() , 'fraud' => rand(0,1));
}
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to redirect to a third party gateway where customers can enter their credit card details then be redirected back to our site.

Comment: I have accepted this as an answer... If you have any experience using this method/module could you tell me how to use the form for redirect instead of: /template/payment/form/ccsave.phtml